# Log4j2.1 and RabbitMQ queue logging

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, logging, rabbitmq, log4j2

i am new to log4j2 and Rabbit MQ , i am trying to log the message the Queue using log4j2, but i am not able to find any tutorial or guide on this can anyone help me on this?

Comment: i am new to log4j2 and Rabbit MQ , i am trying to log the message  to the Queue using log4j2, but i am not able to find any tutorial or guide on this can anyone help me on this?

Comment: log4j2 if for java, RabbitMQ is written in Erlang.

Comment: is there any example or sample ?

Comment: Why log4j2 ? you can use other addOns for Logging.

Comment: even for the addons i dont have any reference in online, could you help me on this